# Is OPAL eDrive (Full-Disk Encryption) composable with Intel Smart Response Techonology?

Tags: windows-8.1, ssd, bitlocker, disk-encryption, opal

I've just ordered a Haswell laptop with a 2.5" SATA hard disk.  According to the service manual it has an mSATA slot (there are also Ultrabooks where a 24GB SSD is pre-installed and pre-configured as cache using Intel SRT).

I'm planning to install a 240GB mSATA SSD and use part as SRT cache and part as the boot disk.  Some of my SSD options (notably the Samsung 840 EVO and Crucial M500) have support for Opal managed full-disk encryption.  The corresponding feature in Windows 8.1 is "Microsoft eDrive", part of BitLocker.

Can both these technologies be used on the same drive?  If so, what is the correct order to enable them?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.
SRT is a software technology and any drive can work with it.

eDrive has to be built into the drive itself.

there is no overlap between these 2 technology.

Comment: But with SRT, the drive is no longer shown to the OS.  Instead a RAID-like volume representing the remaining space is exposed. Will eDrive commands be passed through the Intel layer?